# nodejs: "was not included into executable at compilation stage"

Tags: node.js

I made a scraper tool who using [fingerprint generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprint-generator) and [fingerprint injector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprint-injector) and I wanted to compile it with PKG but the problem is that when I'm starting the script, it show me a error:
`Error: File '/**/node_modules/header-generator/data_files/headers-order.json' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.`

I tried to set the source of the JSON file in the package.json but nothing working at the moment, does someone have a solution ? I hope that my question is enough detailed, thanks for answering!

**Package.json**

```
"pkg": {

    "script": [
      "node_modules/header-generator/data_files/headers-order.json"
    ],
    "assets": [
      "node_modules/header-generator/data_files/headers-order.json"
    ]

}
```